# NullReferenceException being thrown when I try to add a component to a dictionary

Tags: unity

I have the following section of code from a `MonoBehaviour` class in a voxel engine that I'm currently working on right now:

```
public void CreateChunk(Position chunkPosition)
{
    GameObject newChunk = (GameObject)Instantiate(
        this.ChunkPrefab,
        new Vector3(chunkPosition.X, chunkPosition.Y, chunkPosition.Z),
        Quaternion.identity
    );

    Debug.Log("New Chunk", newChunk);

    Chunk newChunkComponent = newChunk.GetComponent<Chunk>();
    newChunkComponent.ChunkPosition = chunkPosition;
    newChunkComponent.ParentTerrainManager = this;

    this._ChunksInMemory.Add(chunkPosition, newChunkComponent);

    for(int x = 0; x < Chunk.GlobalChunkSize; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < Chunk.GlobalChunkSize; y++)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < Chunk.GlobalChunkSize; z++)
            {
                newChunkComponent.CreateBlock(new Position(x, y, z), new Stone());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Chunk` class is also a `MonoBehaviour` class as well. I'm trying to instantiate a chunk prefab and then get the `Chunk` component from the instantiated prefab. Unfortunately I get the following `NullReferenceException`:

> ```
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Voxel.Engine.TerrainManager.CreateChunk (Position chunkPosition) (at Assets/Source/Engine/TerrainManager.cs:99)
> Voxel.Engine.TerrainManager.Start () (at Assets/Source/Engine/TerrainManager.cs:132)
> ```

This is line 99:

```
this._ChunksInMemory.Add(chunkPosition, newChunkComponent);
```

The field `this._ChunksInMemory` is simply a `Dictionary<Position, Chunk>` containing all the currently loaded chunks.

I have done the following things so far:

- I have confirmed that the `TerrainManager` `MonoBehaviour` class (the one that contains the above section of code) does in fact have a chunk prefab assigned:

  [image]
- I have confirmed that there is in fact a copy of the chunk prefab by looking at the hierarchy and calling `Debug.Log("Chunk created", newChunk)`.

  [image]
- I have confirmed that the copy of the chunk prefab has a `Chunk` component attached to it:

  [image]

At this point, I am clueless as to why my code isn't working. Just from looking at the code, it should work fine, but it doesn't. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Likely `this._ChunksInMemory` is the object that is null.  Show where you call `new` for it.

Comment: @Draco18s Yup. That was the issue. I guess this is what happens when I try to code on 2 hours of sleep.

Comment: I see this error all the time. ;D

Comment: @Draco18s You should add your comment as an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based purely on the code you posted, the only object that can be null and cause an NPE is `this._ChunksInMemory`.  It is highly probable that you declared it and forgot to define it with `new`.  Comments indicate I was correct in this assumption.

I see this sort of problem all the time, particularly with new coders (and sleep deprived).  NPEs are among the easiest errors to diagnose and fix.  By knowing what line it occurs on you can use a multitude of debugging techniques to inspect each object on that line to determine which one is null.  Cameron Oltmann's reply about the manual debugger is one such way.  Another is to use `Debug.Log(...)` messages to print out the value of each object on the offending line (although unity will frequently print an empty string for a null object, I don't know why and wish it wouldn't).